# How secure is Google Images

Tags: security, encryption, google-image-search

I am developing a chrome plugin that heavily uses Google Images with users for **medical images**. It's an image classification system, so I need some human results, and I've resorted to use a plugin with some external users.

What it does is tracking user interaction with specific results, in other words, they are presented some results from the search, and then:

- users will select results from the list [as in the first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Oos6.jpg)
- users will select from similar images [as in the second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1aLY.jpg)

They also have the option from the third image to **select to see other similar images** with "View more".

How secure are all these communications? Since I am dealing with health issues, the protocol I need to follow is strict: every communication must be encrypted.

Are all data completely secure, or some steps, as selecting a particular result (pic 1), or choosing similar images within a result (pic 2), are insecure?

This will have a great impact on the plugin development, as I keep track of what every user will do.

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what kind of information would be ok to share freely with Google but not ok to leave unencrypted. If this is HIPAA (US) regulated information, Google has policies which you need to explore & follow: https://support.google.com/a/answer/3407054?hl=en. In any case, this is off topic for StackOverflow since it is regulatory and legal advice, not programming. You will need to discuss with your vendor (Google) and your lawyer and/or compliance officer.

Answer (score 0):

very secure, don't worry. but remember that google uses everything for their benefit and may use them later on

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since I am writing a plugin for medical image classification, I need to be sure. Is there some documentation I can read that says that no communication between my computer and Google will be unencrypted under any circumstances? (provided I use https, of course)